# php difference between include and adding files in bash script and runing cron job

Tags: php, bash, include

I have a file1.php. In this file i have $something_i_need and i then include file1.php in file2.php and echo $something_i_need. Everything works so far. But what if i use a little bash script with

```
#!/bin/sh

 /web/cgi-bin/php5 "$HOME/html/file1.php"
 /web/cgi-bin/php5 "$HOME/html/file2.php".....
```

If i echo $something_i_need in file2.php it doesn't work. Doesn't it remember the stuff from the first file?

I bother with this because i have several files like file2.php and i dont want to include file1.php in every one of them witch would in my opinion (correct me if im wrong) make the script work longer and use more resources.

Is there any way to run file1.php once remember the stuff in it and use it in several files so it would be as smooth as possible (i run cron job every few minutes so i want it to be light)

Comment: Maybe you can use `export` to export your shell variable to make it available to other processes that are running in the same shell instance: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-export-command/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d include all files in one combined script. If the tasks are divided into logical subroutines, do it inside functions or classes, and PHP will collect garbage and free memory after you. If it’s too difficult, you could always `unset` unused variables from the first part, before advancing to the second. This shouldn’t be a performance killer.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a scripting language. Once you run a script, it will do whatever you want from it and then it's done. This applies to both using PHP on a webserver and over the command line.

So once `file1.php` did run, it's done. There isn't a space to "store" any variables and therefore no way for `file2.php` to know about anything `file1.php` did.

As you already said, you can solve your problem by including `file1.php` in all `file2.php`s. Or come up with a solution that includes both the `file1.php` and the `file2.php`s, so everything is just executed once.